# How to keep special characters together in word_tokenize?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, string, nltk

I have NLP problem that involves some coding assignments such as "fn_point->extract.isolate_r" and when I use `word_tokenize`, the assignment "`->`" is split like this `["fn_point-", ">", "extract.isolate_r"]`.

I did the following:

```
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
sentence = "The functional list fn_point->extract.isolate_r of size 32 is not valid"
new_sent = word_tokenize(sentence)
print(new_sent)
```

How to keep "`->`" as one word since it is an assignment operator in c programming language?

Comment: Well, that's not "natural language".  You would have to post-process this to search for "->" and join the tokens around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little bit *ad-hoc* but does the job:

```
from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer

tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer('[\w\.]+|\d+|\->')

tokenizer.tokenize(sentence)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
['The', 'functional', 'list', 'fn_point', '->', 'extract.isolate_r', 'of', 'size', '32', 'is', 'not', 'valid']
```